# Can't install Adobe Flash updates – "An error occurred while downloading the installer"

Tags: windows, proxy, flash-player

I can't install updates of Adobe Flash Player when Windows is starting.

I have a proxy server, but I have configured the proxy settings in Internet Explorer. The error message I get says:

> An error occurred while downloading the installer. Please make sure you are connected to the internet and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this direct link:

- [Flash player for Internet Explorer](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_ax.exe)
- [Flash Player for anything else (Firefox, Opera)](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player.exe)

Then you'll be able to install it manually.

Comment: Downloading the installer is not the problem. The installer then tries to download more stuff, but doesn't use a proxy configured on the system. It's something that Adobe just doesn't bother supporting.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an automatic configuration script in your proxy settings, you might be experiencing [this problem](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2929964).  If so, please vote on the bug.  I don't think Adobe consider it to be important.

If your current version is older than 10.3.183.5, and if you are trying to use the Adobe Updater rather than going to their web site, you might be running into a bug that has already been fixed.  Try going to http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer/ and see if that works.

Or, if all else fails, you can [download full installers](http://www.adobe.com/special/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html).  Although these are provided for distributors they can still be used to install Flash on a single machine.

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked.
I did a couple of things which i don't know which one was related to it.

- Disabled Avast Shield Control for 10 minutes - I have Avast Antivirus installed
- Corrected my time/date settings - My date/time settings were incorrect.
- Closed Firefox before installing the update.

I just gave it a final try and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your system date and time are correct. This error will keep occurring if the date and time is incorrect. I simply corrected the date and time and clicked retry, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around for this issue:
On a system without a proxy, run the web installer, wait for it to download the actual installer and stop before accepting the license terms. Now open your %TEMP% (your system's temp folder), and look for a file named InstallFlashPlayer.exe. Copy that file somewhere to prevent it from being deleted. You can now transfer this installer to other systems and update FlashPlayer there.